# install bcrypt on ubuntu ec2

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm, bcrypt

```
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-                    gyp/lib/build.js:267:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:107:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1045:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 3.2.0-40-virtual
gyp ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/ubuntu/grooform/fungroo/node_modules/bcrypt
gyp ERR! node -v v0.11.12
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v0.12.2
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm ERR! bcrypt@0.8.0 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the bcrypt@0.8.0 install script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the bcrypt package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls bcrypt
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! System Linux 3.2.0-40-virtual
npm ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! cwd /home/ubuntu/grooform/fungroo
npm ERR! node -v v0.11.12
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.3
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR!
```

npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/ubuntu/grooform/fungroo/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0

I have  installed libcurl4-openssl-dev too but still m getting same error
also i have installed python and set HOME to point to /home/ubuntu

can you please help..

TRIED ON A FRESH UBUNTU
getting following error

```
gyp: Call to 'node -e "require('nan')"' returned exit status 1. while trying to load binding.gyp
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/pause/0.0.1
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/usr/share/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:431:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:797:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 3.13.0-36-generic
gyp ERR! command "nodejs" "/usr/bin/node-gyp" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/ubuntu/fungroo/node_modules/bcrypt
gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.25
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v0.10.10
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm WARN This failure might be due to the use of legacy binary "node"
npm WARN For further explanations, please read
/usr/share/doc/nodejs/README.Debian

npm ERR! weird error 1
```

Comment: Can you post the output of `npm --loglevel=silly install bcrypt`?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/SeKHiDux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nan` [has issues](https://github.com/rvagg/nan/issues/178) with some (older) versions of the node v0.11 unstable branch, so you will need to upgrade your unstable node version (v0.11.14 is the latest as of this writing) or use a stable version of node (v0.10.33 as of this writing).